# Firebase's ref().child(stringPath: String) returning the entire top level collection

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve a specific child of my Firebase database using swiftUI. To do that I use the simple expression

```
func addListeners() {
    let database = Database.database(url: "https://someUrl")
    let ref = database.reference(withPath: "users")
    let currentUserId = "u3Ebr6M3BAbP7PBSYYJ7q9kEe1l2"
    let drivingTowardsRef = database.reference(withPath: "users/\(currentUserId)/drivingTowardsUsers")
    print("Loading data from \(drivingTowardsRef)")
    
    //THIS RIGHT HERE IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM
    ref.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
        print("Got TOP LEVEL data for user \(snapshot.key): \(String(describing: snapshot.value))")
    }
    //---------------------------------------
    
    drivingTowardsRef.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
        ref.child(snapshot.key).getData { (error, userSnapshot) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print("Got arriving user data \(snapshot.key): \(String(describing: userSnapshot.value))")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<s>The function will just return the entire database data</s>
EDIT: The function returns the data from the first observer ref top level in this case users/ which in my case has two elements: niixi6iORjNn8gWq6tKvSi3Bxfc2, u3Ebr6M3BAbP7PBSYYJ7q9kEe1l2

```
Got arriving user data niixi6iORjNn8gWq6tKvSi3Bxfc2: Optional({
niixi6iORjNn8gWq6tKvSi3Bxfc2 =     {
    aproxTime = 0;
    distance = 0;
    latitude = "37.33070704";
    longitude = "-122.03039943";
    parkingMode = searching;
    userId = niixi6iORjNn8gWq6tKvSi3Bxfc2;
    username = testeroNumero;
};
u3Ebr6M3BAbP7PBSYYJ7q9kEe1l2 =     {
    aproxTime = 0;
    distance = 0;
    drivingTowardsUsers =         {
        niixi6iORjNn8gWq6tKvSi3Bxfc2 =             {
            approxTime = 0;
            distance = "560.1447571016249";
        };
    };
    latitude = "37.32984184";
    longitude = "-122.02018095";
    parkingMode = offering;
    userId = u3Ebr6M3BAbP7PBSYYJ7q9kEe1l2;
    username = cleoBadu;
};
```

<s>The key for the child path I pass him seems to be correct but it's still returning the entire top level collection instead of the single item...</s>

**EDIT**: The problem seems to be on the first observer which messes up the .getData() of the ref.child(snapshot.key). Is that even possible?

Just commenting out that ref.observe(.childAdded) will automatically make the second ref.child(snapshot.key) behave totally normally
What am I missing?

I could get the entire database as a single mega dictionary and then get the child I want from there but it doesn't seem really conventional, especially when google's library offers the possibility to not do that.

<s>**EDIT**: I added a printing statement that prints the url of the database ref. If I then type in the url on my browser, it redirects me on the FRT database and landing me on the correct object. So the url it's generating is correct and works perfectly fine.
Still the object returned by the getData() is the entire db</s>

SN: I removed all codable structs as that is not the problem, so the question is more focused on the actual problem

**EDIT**: Created a simple view as that. On a clean project it works on my project it doesn't. I guess it's some sort of configuration but's it's hard to look into it.

**PROBLEM**: Whatever child(string) I pass him it returns the entire top level data either way (replacing so snapshot.key). For example: I pass the key "something" -> all users are returned, I pass the key "" all users are returned

Comment: Could you post the full code please?

Comment: Added full code

Comment: Post the `ParkingUser Codable` struct too & your firebase structure in image

Comment: Added also the codable struct

Comment: I tried reproducing the problem, but am unable to. Since the info is too long for a comment, I wrote it up as an answer below.

Comment: "I pass the key "something" -> the entire database is returned, I pass the key "" the entire database is returned" As shown in my answer, I get back exactly the data that your code is observing. Are you using the same SDK version that I'm using?

Comment: Can you try to add the lines of code commented with //THIS RIGHT HERE IS THE PROBLEM to your your snippet. I think I just found the problem

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to reproduce the problem with (mostly) your code and data, but am not getting the same behavior.

I put the equivalent data into a database of mine at: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/68956236.json?print=pretty

And used this code in Xcode 1.2 with Firebase SDK version 8.6.1:

```
let ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference().child("68956236")
let currentUserId: String = "u3Ebr6M3BAbP7PBSYYJ7q9kEe1l2"

let drivingTowardsRef: DatabaseReference! = ref.child("\(currentUserId)/drivingTowardsUsers");
print("Loading data from \(drivingTowardsRef)")

drivingTowardsRef.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
    ref.child(snapshot.key).getData { (error, userSnapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
        
            do {
                //let parkingUser =  try userSnapshot.data(as: ParkingUser.self)
                print("Got data for user \(snapshot.key): \(String(describing: userSnapshot.value))")
            } catch {
                print("There has been an error while decoding the user location data with uid \(snapshot.key), the object to be decoded was \(userSnapshot). The decode failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

> Loading data from Optional(https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/68956236/u3Ebr6M3BAbP7PBSYYJ7q9kEe1l2/drivingTowardsUsers)
>
> 2021-08-27 10:39:09.578043-0700 Firebase10[36407:3458780] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
>
> Got data for user niixi6iORjNn8gWq6tKvSi3Bxfc2: Optional({
> aproxTime = 0;
> distance = 0;
> latitude = "37.32798355";
> longitude = "-122.01982712";
> parkingMode = searching;
> userId = niixi6iORjNn8gWq6tKvSi3Bxfc2;
> username = testeroNumero;
> })

As far as I can see this behavior is correct, but different from what you get. I hope knowing that I don't see the same behavior, and what versions I use, may be helpful to you.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the time taken to reproduce it! Is child("68956236")? a sub collection you made purposely for the test?

Comment: There's no concept of collection/subcollection in Firebase's Realtime Database, but the `68956236` is indeed a node in my database for this test (it's the ID of your question). You can see the contents of the node in the link I added in my question, as I made it publicly readable.

Comment: I tried updating to 8.6.1 I'm trying rn to reproduce the error on a vanilla project, if it persists I'll try to edit my post adding the GitHub link

Comment: I don't think we need *more* code here. I'd rather you try to reproduce it with as little code and data as possible, as I did in my post. For example: if you're getting the wrong data back, the `Codable` class shouldn't matter - which is why I simply print the value from the data snapshot and never even used the `ParkingUser`. Less code makes it more likely that we're looking at the same thing. I'd typically recommend an inverted approach: try to get a working mini-app with my code first, and then see if you can break it like is happening in your question.

Comment: I think this happens because Codable expects a Value of Double but firebase returns a string?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated the question, it's now cleaner and focused on the real problem. Basically I created a sample project with the same library version, same database structure, same observer. It perfectly worked. On my old project however it keeps not working. I also printed the url it's about to call, and the url brings be to the database with the expected object open, so the url is calling si correct! I don't know where to look for, the function is just as simple as getData -> print statement as of now

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found the problem, basically it's one observer I got on the top level ref. It's causing me problems with the getData of the child items. Is that even possible? I updated the question with all the necessary info

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with Firebase but rather client-side handling of the data returned, You’re expecting a Double within your Codable struct but supplying a String in the other end— Can you try:

```
public struct ParkingUser: Codable {
    var latitude: String
    var longitude: String
}
```

Comment: I removed all codable structs and decoding statements, as the problem is not there. I updated the question, it's cleaner and more focused. Thanks a lot